# R: Selection of rows in data frame includes NA

Tags: r, na

My data looks like this after import

```
A = data.frame( ID= c(1,2,3,4,5,6), Name = c(NA,"A",NA,NA,NA,"B"))

>A
ID Name
1 <NA>
2    A
3 <NA>
4 <NA>
5 <NA>
6    B
```

I expect this result, when I select all rows with Name=="A":

```
   ID Name
2  2    A
```

However, I get 5 rows:

```
> A[A$Name=="A",]
     ID Name
NA   NA <NA>
2     2    A
NA.1 NA <NA>
NA.2 NA <NA>
NA.3 NA <NA>
```

Note that I do not look for `complete.cases()` since there are many more columns in the data frame. And I also did specify the `na.strings` parameter during `read.csv(...,na.strings = NA)`. The missing values are not "NA" but NA in the csv file and playing around with that during import did not change anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see the result you need, try this:

```
> subset(A,Name=="A")
  ID Name
2  2    A
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
> A[which(A$Name=="A"), ]
  ID Name
2  2    A
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `%in%` instead of `==`:

```
A[A$Name %in% "A", ]
#   ID Name
#2  2    A
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is apparently desired behaviour of R.

Try

```
A = data.frame( ID= c(1,2,3,4,5,6), Name = c(NA,"A",NA,NA,NA,"B"))

A[A$Name=="A" & !is.na(A$Name),]
   ID Name
2  2    A
```

This is because comparing NA to a value equates to NA and not TRUE or FALSE

```
"B" == "A"
[1] FALSE
"A" == "A"
[1] TRUE
NA == "A"
[1] NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way by setting 'Name' as the key column after converting to `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A, key='Name')['A']
#   ID Name
#1:  2    A
```